# displaying images using for loop in html

Tags: python, html, django-models, django-templates, responsive-images

I am pretty new to django and now I'm currently learning how to access images in database and display it using html. I want to put the images as elements in a list for further styling and making the page responsive using css but I don't want to write each and every image as a list item as there are more than 100 images in database. I've tried the below code but its not displaying images as a list. Please do suggest if any better way of doing it. I have `image` as a model in my `models.py`.

```
<div class='gallery'>
  {% for x in photo %}
  <ul>
    <li><img class="images" src="{{x.image.url}}"/></li>
  </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the model for reference:

```
from django.db import models
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_uploader = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="home/images")
```

This is the view:

```
def profile(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        photos_to_show = []
        username = request.user.username
        photos = Photo.objects.filter(photo_uploader=username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'name': username, 'photo': photos})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ul>` tags should be placed *outside* the loop, otherwise you each time start a new `<ul>` and end that `</ul>` *per* image:

```
<div class='gallery'>
  <ul>
  {% for x in photo %}
    <li><img class="images" src="{{ x.image.url }}"/></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! it does work but I'm not able to apply some properties  like display and flex to them.